# Sharing iPhone Apps for the Simulator

Tags: macos, testing, ios-simulator

iPhone Apps built for the simulator are stored here:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications
```

Is it possible to copy the **<GUID>.sb** and **<GUID>** directory and install them on a different computer (with Development tools installed)?

This would be very useful for testing/demoing with out having to buy iPhones for all the managers and external clients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you send those files to another person, and they put them into that directory, they can test the applications in the iPhone Simulator as well :)

Answer (score 11):

I found a way that requires just a little more setup, but is much easier for non-developers:

### Instructions for your users/testers:

1. Install Xcode following Apple's instructions
2. Double-click the attached application - the iPhone simulator will launch, install the app and start it automatically.

### How to set it up:

1. Download and unzip (to a folder on your desktop or wherever) 'Simulator Bundler' from: http://github.com/landonf/simlaunch/downloads
2. Set your XCode build target to the required Simulator configuration (iPad/iPhone/which iOS version)
3. Do a 'Build and archive'
4. Find it: select 'Archived applications' in the Organizer, right click the relevant build, select "Reveal archived application in Finder"
5. Drag the application (yourAppName, no extension) onto the Simulator Bundler app

Done. This will create a self-contained Mac OS X yourAppDisplayName.app file in the same folder (with your app's icon as the icon) that you can stick up on an FTP server or email to your users/testers.

--

I think it's much neater/slicker than having to explain where to copy files, how to launch the simulator and so on.. And if anything gets messed up they can just uninstall via the familiar tap-and-hold + (x) gesture in the simulator UI, then double-click the app you sent them again.

You can also produce several of these packages changing the bundle identifier between builds, allowing them to be installed side by side in your testers' simulators; say for getting some user feedback on different UI designs, or configure one for Production and one for Staging/QA servers, so your content editors can check their changes before they go live or whatever..

The ability to reinstall the app from a desktop icon is also very convenient for localisation testing: launch the simulator, uninstall the app if present, set the required region format and language, double click the icon on your desktop, test; repeat for each required locale. (guarantees a fresh install each time, I've found that switching language with the app installed can result in all sorts of strange behaviour)

Comment: Super cool... but does it work with iPad simulator builds...?

Comment: Yep works with iPad just the same :) just re-reading my instructions though, steps 2 and 3 are basically to do with finding the relevant simulator binary, so I guess I didn't realise at the time but you need to have the simulator (iPhone or iPad as required) set as the build target (so it compiles an Intel/x86 binary) for the steps to work. Alternatively not sure if I tried this, but it should work if you build into the simulator as usual, close the app with the home button and locate the app in the simulator's folder structure.

Comment: This no longer works with the latest version of xcode from the app store.

Comment: Just build don't do an archive, since this is only available when you're build for ARM based archs. After this go to the Xcode Organizer (⇧⌘2) and select the `Projects` from the top bar. On the left, find your project (its indicated with a blue dot). Click on the right arrow  next to the `Derived Data` label. Now drag the IPA onto the `Simulator Bundle` app icon.