# How to distribute an iPhone app BEFORE the sale date without getting UDIDs or jailbreaking?

Tags: iphone, testing, udid

I've got an app that's approved by Apple and ready-for-sale, but we're holding off for a few days for press reasons. Anyone know of a way to distribute this thing to beta testers without dealing with UDIDs or jailbreaking phones? Does it matter that it's approved, can I just give select users a file without the provisional stuff?

Answer (score 3):

Try distributing a promotional code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a distribution without device IDs. Even the App Store uses device IDs but its hidden and Apple manages it for you.

The hardware device IDs are the core to of the IP protection system. You can't get around them without jailbreaking.

Answer (score 0):

Promo codes. Turns out they are available through iTunes Connect homepage as soon as the app is approved, even if it hasn't gone live in the iTunes store yet.

Answer (score 0):

If your beta testers have Macs you could create an auto-installer for the iPhone Simulator as described here:

[Sharing iPhone Apps for the Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932480/sharing-iphone-apps-for-the-simulator/3493270#3493270)