# Is it possible to distribute an iOS app for simulator testing on MacOS?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I'm in the early alpha stages of an iOS app and I'd like to be able to deploy it to some non-technical people within my company for early feedback.  It's premature to deploy it to physical devices, and not all the people have them anyway.

What I'd like to do is somehow install the iOS `.app` file into the simulator app, and bundle that into a MacOS `.app` file that I can just email to people and have them run just by clicking on it.

Second best, but acceptable, would be to have the users install Xcode and have a way to send them the iOS `.app` file and have some sort of script that would load the app into the already installed simulator app.

This seems like it ought to be possible, but I can't find any way to accomplish it.

**Note**: There is a LOT of advice online about things like TestFlight or Over-The-Air apps, but that involves the physical hardware, which is **not** what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: wouldn't Simulator be required then, thus making xcode neccesary and just sending them the project would be just as easy. Or you could just show them your iphone and let them try it on that.

Comment: Ideally, there would be a tool that would link the Simulator code into a free-standing MacOS application that could be run on a Mac without having to install Xcode.  But it would also be acceptable to have people install Xcode and then package the app into something that would load up and run in the Simulator on their machine, but without them having to understand anything about it.  These are non-technical people, so I can't send them source code or require complex installation steps.  And I can't just show them my iPhone because we're in different physical locations.

Comment: Oh - IDK What your job is, but you could try to find one technical person there to install it on a cheap device (iPT) so they could try it. (If they are in another office)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the idea in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3493270/349974), I used [SimLaunch](https://github.com/landonf/simlaunch), which packages your iOS `.app file` into a MacOS `.app` file.  The recipient has to install Xcode, but once that's done, he/she just runs the app and the app invokes the simulator, with your iOS app installed.  It totally works.

One potentially tricky thing: when you run SimLaunch, it asks you for the location of your iOS app.  When you tell it, it creates the output MacOS app in the same location, with a file name like `YourApp (iPhone Simulator).app`, but doesn't give any message telling you this, and it says running, so it looks like the app is just frozen.  In fact, it's done and waiting for more work, but it took me a while to realize this.