# Installing app in other computer's iOS simulator and localized strings only appear in English

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, ios-simulator

When I run one application in the iOS simulator from Xcode, it installs the app in the simulator(obvious), and if later on I close the app, go to the settings in the simulator and change the language my application will show me the corresponding localized strings in the selected language, as expected.

My problem is that if I install that application into a workmate's simulator(copying the corresponding folder into his simulator's Applications folder) the app works fine but when you change the simulator's language the application does not behave as expected and it still shows the EN strings... This does not happen if that workmate runs the app from Xcode, only pasting an app that has been build in other computer.

I have tried to find a solution following [this question's second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932480/sharing-iphone-apps-for-the-simulator) but seems that it does not work with the current Xcode version.

Any idea/workaround/solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Before running the App you need to clean the build as it retains the old setting if you are not cleaning the build. Try using 'cmd+shift+K' and then run on simulator. It should be fine.

Comment: That does not make sense since I do not want to build the app in the second computer, just to install it in its simulator.